# Fit longtable to width of latex document

Tags: tables, longtable

I am having the problem of fitting a latex table to my document:

```
\begin{longtable}{|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|l|l|l|p{2cm}|l|l|}
\hline
\textbf{}                         & {\ul \textbf{oenb\_dependent}} & {\ul \textbf{carReg}} & {\ul \textbf{cpi}} & {\ul \textbf{primConstTot}} & {\ul \textbf{resProp.Dwell}} & {\ul \textbf{cbre.office.primeYield}} & {\ul \textbf{cbre.retail.capitalValue}} \\ \hline
\textit{Number of Values}         & 57,00                          & 57,00                 & 57,00              & 57,00                       & 57,00                        & 57,00                                 & 57,00                                   \\ \hline
\textit{Number of Missing Values} & 0,00                           & 0,00                  & 0,00               & 0,00                        & 0,00                         & 0,00                                  & 0,00                                    \\ \hline
\textit{Min}                      & -9,23                          & -27,11                & -5,38              & -3,36                       & -12,10                       & -1,00                                 & -1882,35                                \\ \hline
\textit{Max}                      & 11,26                          & 17,55                 & 1,28               & 2,40                        & 11,30                        & 0,40                                  & 1386,67                                 \\ \hline
\textit{Range}                    & 20,49                          & 44,66                 & 6,66               & 5,76                        & 23,40                        & 1,40                                  & 3269,02                                 \\ \hline
\textit{Sum}                      & 0,77                           & -2,53                 & -88,41             & -37,13                      & -45,90                       & 2,40                                  & -12800,35                               \\ \hline
\textit{Median}                   & -0,22                          & 0,24                  & -1,40              & -0,43                       & -0,40                        & 0,05                                  & 0,00                                    \\ \hline
\textit{Mean}                     & 0,01                           & -0,04                 & -1,55              & -0,65                       & -0,81                        & 0,04                                  & -224,57                                 \\ \hline
\textit{SE of Mean}               & 0,57                           & 1,05                  & 0,21               & 0,11                        & 0,48                         & 0,04                                  & 69,92                                   \\ \hline
\textit{95\% CI of Mean}          & 1,13                           & 2,09                  & 0,42               & 0,23                        & 0,96                         & 0,07                                  & 140,08                                  \\ \hline
\textit{Variance}                 & 18,25                          & 62,31                 & 2,49               & 0,74                        & 13,06                        & 0,08                                  & 278697,92                               \\ \hline
\textit{Std. Dev.}                & 4,27                           & 7,89                  & 1,58               & 0,86                        & 3,61                         & 0,28                                  & 527,92                                  \\ \hline
\textit{Coef. Var.}               & 317,97                         & -177,59               & -1,02              & -1,32                       & -4,49                        & 6,64                                  & -2,35                                   \\ \hline
\caption{Output of pre-selected and finally chosen variables of the variable selection process.}
\label{table:initialDataSet}
\end{longtable}
```

As you can see the table goes beyond the border:

[image]

I am trying to use `p{2cm}` for fitting the table, but it still does not work.

Any suggestions, how to fit the table properly to my document?

Comment: Of course the problem are the column headers, which are too long.

Comment: By the way, I'm not sure about `longtable`: won't a standard `tabular` do? It doesn't seem like a table that should be split across pages.

Comment: @egreg I also tried a standard `tabular`, but this also does not fit...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no hope of fitting a table with such long headers. A way out can be using symbols for them, that are explained at the bottom of the table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,siunitx,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering

\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{-3pt}

\begin{tabular}{
  @{}
  >{\itshape}l
  S[table-format=3.2]
  S[table-format=-3.2]
  S[table-format=-2.2]
  S[table-format=-2.2]
  S[table-format=-2.2]
  S[table-format=-1.2]
  S[table-format=-5.2]
  @{}
}
\toprule
& {(1)} &{(2)} &{(3)} &{(4)} & {(5)} &{(6)} & {(7)} \\
\midrule
\textit{Values}          &  57,00 &   57,00 &  57,00 &  57,00 &  57,00 & 57,00 &     57,00 \\
\textit{Missing Values}  &   0,00 &    0,00 &   0,00 &   0,00 &   0,00 &  0,00 &      0,00 \\
\textit{Min}             &  -9,23 &  -27,11 &  -5,38 &  -3,36 & -12,10 & -1,00 &  -1882,35 \\
\textit{Max}             &  11,26 &   17,55 &   1,28 &   2,40 &  11,30 &  0,40 &   1386,67 \\
\textit{Range}           &  20,49 &   44,66 &   6,66 &   5,76 &  23,40 &  1,40 &   3269,02 \\
\textit{Sum}             &   0,77 &   -2,53 & -88,41 & -37,13 & -45,90 &  2,40 & -12800,35 \\
\textit{Median}          &  -0,22 &    0,24 &  -1,40 &  -0,43 &  -0,40 &  0,05 &      0,00 \\
\textit{Mean}            &   0,01 &   -0,04 &  -1,55 &  -0,65 &  -0,81 &  0,04 &   -224,57 \\
\textit{SE of Mean}      &   0,57 &    1,05 &   0,21 &   0,11 &   0,48 &  0,04 &     69,92 \\
\textit{95\% CI of Mean} &   1,13 &    2,09 &   0,42 &   0,23 &   0,96 &  0,07 &    140,08 \\
\textit{Variance}        &  18,25 &   62,31 &   2,49 &   0,74 &  13,06 &  0,08 & 278697,92 \\
\textit{Std.\ Dev.}      &   4,27 &    7,89 &   1,58 &   0,86 &   3,61 &  0,28 &    527,92 \\
\textit{Coef.\ Var.}     & 317,97 & -177,59 &  -1,02 &  -1,32 &  -4,49 &  6,64 &     -2,35 \\
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
%%% Headers
\multicolumn{8}{l}{(1) \textbf{oenb\_dependent}} \\
\multicolumn{8}{l}{(2) \textbf{carReg}} \\
\multicolumn{8}{l}{(3) \textbf{cpi}} \\
\multicolumn{8}{l}{(4) \textbf{primConstTot}} \\
\multicolumn{8}{l}{(5) \textbf{resProp.Dwell}} \\
\multicolumn{8}{l}{(6) \textbf{cbre.office.primeYield}} \\
\multicolumn{8}{l}{(7) \textbf{cbre.retail.capitalValue}} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\caption{Output of pre-selected and finally chosen variables of the variable selection process.}
\label{table:initialDataSet}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I also recommend `siunitx` and `booktabs`, that give more professional appearance to the table. The value after `table-format` is the number of digits in the integer and decimal part, with an optional sign if present in the column. In column one I don't specify the sign, because it's taken care of by the last entry; similarly for the sixth column, the two digit first entry is taken care of by the minus sign.

Since the table was still overfull by about 41pt, I removed 3pt of separation between columns (two spaces are inserted between columns, and 6 times 7 makes 42).

[image]

Comment: you declare the first column to be in `\itshape`, so the text in it not need to be enclosed with `\textit{ ...}` any more :-)

Answer (score 2):

A variant, using `ltablex` which combines the possibilities of `tabularx` and `longtable`,. The description of the letters in column head are done with the `threeparttablex` package, which brings the functionalities of `threeparttable` to long tables splitting across pages. Finally I loaded the `geometry` package for more sensible margins, if you don't need wide marginal notes, and booktabs for its vertical padding of horizontal rules.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[labelfont=sc]{caption}

%\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker ={,}, table-format=-2.2}
\usepackage{ltablex, threeparttablex, booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{ThreePartTable}
  \setTableNoteFont{\bfseries}
  \begin{TableNotes}[para, flushleft]\smallskip
    \item[A] oenb\_dependent
    \item[B] carReg
    \item[C] cpi
    \item[D] primConstTot
    \item[E] resProp.Dwell
    \item[F] cbre.office.primeYield
    \item[G] cbre.retail.capitalValue
  \end{TableNotes}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{
      @{}
      >{\itshape}X
      S[table-format=3.2]
      S[table-format=-3.2]
      SSS
      S[table-format=-1.2]
      S[table-format=-5.2]
      @{}}
      %
      & {\bfseries A} & {\bfseries B} & {\bfseries C} & {\bfseries D} & {\bfseries E} & {\bfseries F} & {\bfseries G} \\ \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
      Number of Values & 57,00 & 57,00 & 57,00 & 57,00 & 57,00 & 57,00 & 57,00 \\ \midrule
      Number of Missing Values & 0,00 & 0,00 & 0,00 & 0,00 & 0,00 & 0,00 & 0,00 \\ \midrule
      Min & -9,23 & -27,11 & -5,38 & -3,36 & -12,10 & -1,00 & -1882,35 \\ \midrule
      Max & 11,26 & 17,55 & 1,28 & 2,40 & 11,30 & 0,40 & 1386,67 \\ \midrule
      Range & 20,49 & 44,66 & 6,66 & 5,76 & 23,40 & 1,40 & 3269,02 \\ \midrule
      Sum & 0,77 & -2,53 & -88,41 & -37,13 & -45,90 & 2,40 & -12800,35 \\ \midrule
      Median & -0,22 & 0,24 & -1,40 & -0,43 & -0,40 & 0,05 & 0,00 \\ \midrule
      Mean & 0,01 & -0,04 & -1,55 & -0,65 & -0,81 & 0,04 & -224,57 \\ \midrule
      SE of Mean & 0,57 & 1,05 & 0,21 & 0,11 & 0,48 & 0,04 & 69,92 \\ \midrule
      95\% CI of Mean & 1,13 & 2,09 & 0,42 & 0,23 & 0,96 & 0,07 & 140,08 \\ \midrule
      Variance & 18,25 & 62,31 & 2,49 & 0,74 & 13,06 & 0,08 & 278697,92 \\ \midrule
      Std. Dev. & 4,27 & 7,89 & 1,58 & 0,86 & 3,61 & 0,28 & 527,92 \\ \midrule
      Coef. Var. & 317,97 & -177,59 & -1,02 & -1,32 & -4,49 & 6,64 & -2,35 \\
      \bottomrule
      \insertTableNotes \\
      \caption{Output of pre-selected and finally chosen variables of the variable selection process.}
      \label{table:initialDataSet}
    \end{tabularx}
  \end{ThreePartTable}

\end{document}
```

[image]